Create login and logout rows from single row
I have login and logout like this.
DECLARE @t TABLE
           (
               id INT IDENTITY(1, 1), 
               empid VARCHAR(10), 
               logindate DATE, 
               logintime TIME, 
               logoutdate DATE, 
               logouttime TIME
           )

INSERT @t (empid, logindate, logintime, logoutdate, logouttime) VALUES('251803', CAST(N'2024-06-28T00:00:00.000' AS DATETIME), CAST(N'1899-12-30T08:00:00.000' AS TIME), CAST(N'2024-06-28T00:00:00.000' AS DATETIME), CAST(N'1899-12-30T11:00:00.000' AS TIME))
INSERT @t (empid, logindate, logintime, logoutdate, logouttime) VALUES ('251803', CAST(N'2024-06-28T00:00:00.000' AS DATETIME), CAST(N'1899-12-30T12:00:00.000' AS TIME), CAST(N'2024-06-28T00:00:00.000' AS DATETIME), CAST(N'1899-12-30T16:59:00.003' AS TIME))
INSERT @t (empid, logindate, logintime, logoutdate, logouttime) VALUES ('251809', CAST(N'2024-06-28T00:00:00.000' AS DATETIME), CAST(N'1899-12-30T08:00:00.000' AS TIME), CAST(N'2024-06-28T00:00:00.000' AS DATETIME), CAST(N'1899-12-30T10:14:00.003' AS TIME))
INSERT @t (empid, logindate, logintime, logoutdate, logouttime) VALUES ('251809', CAST(N'2024-06-28T00:00:00.000' AS DATETIME), CAST(N'1899-12-30T11:13:00.000' AS TIME), CAST(N'2024-06-28T00:00:00.000' AS DATETIME), CAST(N'1899-12-30T17:20:00.003' AS TIME))
INSERT @t (empid, logindate, logintime, logoutdate, logouttime) VALUES ('251800', CAST(N'2024-06-28T00:00:00.000' AS DATETIME), CAST(N'1899-12-30T08:00:00.000' AS TIME), CAST(N'2024-06-28T00:00:00.000' AS DATETIME), CAST(N'1899-12-30T13:08:00.003' AS TIME))
INSERT @t (empid, logindate, logintime, logoutdate, logouttime) VALUES('251800', CAST(N'2024-06-28T00:00:00.000' AS DATETIME), CAST(N'1899-12-30T14:08:00.003' AS TIME), CAST(N'2024-06-28T00:00:00.000' AS DATETIME), CAST(N'1899-12-30T17:00:00.003' AS TIME))
INSERT @t (empid, logindate, logintime, logoutdate, logouttime) VALUES ('251800', CAST(N'2024-06-28T00:00:00.000' AS DATETIME), CAST(N'1899-12-30T18:00:00.003' AS TIME), CAST(N'2024-06-28T00:00:00.000' AS DATETIME), CAST(N'1899-12-30T18:00:00.003' AS TIME))
INSERT @t (empid, logindate, logintime, logoutdate, logouttime) VALUES('251800', CAST(N'2024-06-28T00:00:00.000' AS DATETIME), CAST(N'1899-12-30T20:08:00.003' AS TIME), CAST(N'2024-06-28T00:00:00.000' AS DATETIME), CAST(N'1899-12-30T21:00:00.003' AS TIME))

I need to output it like this:

I wrote this SQL script
DECLARE @clock TABLE 
               (
                   i INT IDENTITY,  
                   empid VARCHAR(10), 
                   datetimelog DATETIME, 
                   log_status VARCHAR(10), 
                   punch VARCHAR(10)
               )

DECLARE @i INT = 1, @pnum INT, @curempid VARCHAR(10)

DECLARE @empid VARCHAR(10), 
        @logindate DATE, @logintime TIME, 
        @logoutdate DATE, @logouttime TIME

WHILE (@i <= (SELECT MAX(id)FROM @t))
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        @empid = empid, 
        @logindate = logindate, @logintime = logintime, 
        @logoutdate = logoutdate, @logouttime = logouttime
    FROM 
        @t 
    WHERE 
        id = @i 
    ORDER BY 
        empid, logindate

        
    IF (@curempid IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        SET @curempid = @empid
        SET @pnum = 1
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        IF (@curempid = @empid)
        BEGIN
            SET @pnum = @pnum + 1
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @curempid = @empid
            SET @pnum = 1
        END
    END

    INSERT INTO @clock (empid, datetimelog, log_status, punch)
    VALUES (@empid, CAST(@logindate AS DATETIME) + CAST(CAST(@logintime AS TIME) AS DATETIME), 'IN', @pnum)
        
    SET @pnum = @pnum + 1
        
    INSERT INTO @clock (empid, datetimelog, log_status, punch)
    VALUES (@empid, CAST(@logoutdate AS DATETIME) + CAST(CAST(@logouttime AS TIME) AS DATETIME), 'OUT', @pnum)

    SET @i = @i + 1;
END;

Is there a better way of doing this? I think pivot, but I don't know the pivot way. Thanks in advance

Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

mssql brother..

You can just union two result sets made from the same table and then add a ROW_NUMBER() using the window function to achieve this.
Since you didn't mention your RDBMS I didn't combine your date and timestamp together since that will be specific to the platform. Also, if you are on an older version MySQL that doesn't support window functions, this logic will need to be changed.
SELECT empid,
    datelog,
    timelog,
    log_status,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY empid ORDER BY datelog, timelod) as punch
FROM 
  (
    SELECT empid, 
        logindate as datelog, 
        logintime as timelog, 
        CAST('IN' as VARCHAR(10)) as log_status,
    FROM @t 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT empid, 
        logoutdate,
        logouttime, 
        'OUT',
    FROM @t 
  )dt 
ORDER BY empid, datelog, timelog


As you are on SQL Server you can use CROSS APPLY ... VALUES to unpivot each source row into two output rows. DB Fiddle
WITH T AS
(
SELECT 
        2 * ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY empid ORDER BY id)-1 AS punch_base,
        2 * ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id)-1 AS i_base,
        *
FROM @t
)
SELECT i = i_base + base_offset,
       empid,
       datelog, 
       timelog,
       log_status,
       punch = punch_base + base_offset
FROM T
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
    (logindate, logintime, 'IN', 0),
    (logoutdate, logouttime, 'OUT', 1)
)V(datelog, timelog, log_status, base_offset)

