SQL want to calculate time hours and mints of each emp
I am trying to get total hours and mints of each emp from SQL database date wise from date time column below snap for your refrence please need your support how to do.
There is type column as well where with entry 0 and 1 its mean 0 IN and 1 Out.
Below picture for your reference how I have data in SQL and how I need report.


Please do not use images (as specified in the question guidelines), use table markdown

And I assume you mean minutes not mints?

And the images are identical? Why post them twice!

Where is your code! What have you tried so far? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. You are expected to try to write the code yourself. After doing more research  if you have a problem you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and providing a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Try a query using DATEDIFF(minute,[Time In], [Time Out]) as [Total Minutes].   The follow this example to get it formatted as Hours and Minutes  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733616/how-to-convert-number-of-minutes-to-hhmm-format-in-tsql

Wasn't this asked like a couple of days ago? Albeit with darkmode images https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78693913/create-login-and-logout-rows-from-single-row

How do you want the results formatted when an employee clocks in at 11pm and clocks out after midnight?

How do you want the results formatted when an employee works more than 48 hours?

How do you want the results formatted when an employee has multiple in/out per day, or multiple ins with 0 outs, or multiple outs with 0 ins, or a strange mismatch of in/outs for a day?

I used a CTE to breakup the calculations and make it more readable. If each employee has only 2 records per day then min/max can be used and the InOut flag ignored.
WITH CTE as
(  
SELECT CONVERT(date, TimeDate) as [Date], 
       EmpNumber,  
       CAST(Min(TimeDate) as time) as TimeIN, 
       CAST(Max(TimeDate) as time) as TimeOut ,
       DATEDIFF(minute,CAST(Min(TimeDate) as time),CAST(Max(TimeDate) as time)) as TotalMinutes           
FROM TableEntry
GROUP BY CONVERT(date, TimeDate),EmpNumber
)
SELECT [Date], EmpNumber, 
       RIGHT('0'+CAST(DATEPART(hour, TimeIN) as varchar(2)),2) + ':' +
       RIGHT('0'+CAST(DATEPART(minute, TimeIN)as varchar(2)),2) as TimeIn,
       RIGHT('0'+CAST(DATEPART(hour, TimeOut) as varchar(2)),2) + ':' +
       RIGHT('0'+CAST(DATEPART(minute, TimeOut)as varchar(2)),2) as TimeOut,      
       CAST(TotalMinutes / 60 AS VARCHAR(8)) + ':' + FORMAT(TotalMinutes % 60, 'D2') as TotalMinutes
FROM CTE

fiddle



Date
EmpNumber
TimeIn
TimeOut
TotalMinutes




2024-07-02
100001
09:23
19:06
9:43


2024-07-03
100001
09:37
19:23
9:46




One way to handle scenario where employee works past midnight https://dbfiddle.uk/LYu1Ri87

Thank you for your quick reply only one issue some of employee has multiple IN and OUT and second issue is if any one missed the punch like Missed IN or Out then time should not show and Result should be zero. but as per your query that is great but only issue that if any punch missed both column showing same time and result showing zero which is correct. Please help me for this also.
